# Create Wearable app to existing Android App?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, wear-os

I am trying to create a wearable app to my existing Android App.

Using Android Studio, I was able to create a Mobile App & Wearable App together. Now, I want to use this Wearable App inside my existing Android App .

How can we do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone the wear module inside your existing project (or build it manually) as the new project.

Add in your `settings.gradle` the new module.
You should have something like this:

```
include ':myApp', ':wear'
```

In your app, in the `build.gradle` you have to add:

```
dependencies {
    // your current dependencies
    wearApp project(':wear')
    // may be you have to use also gplay services lib. It depends by your app.
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77'
}
```

**Pay attention to package**.
The wear and the mobile app use the same package!